# The homoclinic orbit in the plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Homoclinic orbit is defined as the intersection of stable and unstable manifold. In 2d case, dimension of both of 1 and they intersect at equilibrium point, so how can we have homoclinic orbit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They may intersect tangent to each other. Think of an equilibrium point and connect it with itself with a single orbit, this single orbit is a homoclinic orbit and is part of the stable and the unstable manifold.